# Pattern for navigating to same screen with different action in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have 2 different modules/features that will navigate to the same screen, and that screen is a form with a button to submit. The problem is:

- If user presses "submit" when navigated from the Module 1, the user's input will just be stored (client-side)
- If user presses "submit" when navigated from the Module 2, the user's input will be sent to server

How can I achieved this? My solution is passing the module name as route param and handle the condition logic at the target screen. However, it will make the target screen has more complicated logic, and modules will depend on each other. I wonder if there is any better solution?

Comment: Yes, You can achieve it by passing param in route

Comment: @NensiKasundra thanks for replying. Like I said, this solution has some cons, so I want to know if there is any better one